# Firebase get some data from snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

```
{
  "OrnekUserId": {
    "AccessToken": "asd",
    "CreatedAt": "2017/12/10",
    "DeletedAt": -1,
    "Email": "deneme@deneme.com",
    "FirstName": "deneme",
    "LastName": "denemeSoyad",
    "LoginType": 0,
    "Phone": "",
    "ThumbNailUrl": "",
    "UpdatedAt": -1,
    "UserName": "denemeName"
  }
}
```

[image]

I get this json data with searching email finally I got this, but there is one another problem you see ' ali ' this is my user id column and it always change for every person.

I'm trying to get username and userid ('ali') column value, but iIcouldn't do it.

Here is my code

```
exports.ForgotPassword = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    const email = req.query.Email;
    if (email == "" || email == null) {
        return res.json({
            result: "E-mail can not be null"
        })
    } else {
        const ref = admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('Email').equalTo(email).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val() == null) {
                return res.json({
                    response: false
                })
            } else {
                return res.json({
                    response: snapshot.val()
                })

            }
        })
    }
})
```

On the last else state I need to get "UserName": "asdada" and "ali"

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but his may give a result :

```
exports.ForgotPassword = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    const email = req.query.Email;
    if (email == "" || email == null) {
        return res.json({
            result: "E-mail can not be null"
        })
    } else {
        return admin.database().ref('Users').orderByChild('Email').equalTo(email).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                return res.send(snapshot.val());   
            } 
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Abi problem şu ben örnek json daki veri gibi her kullanıcıyı id'si altında tutmaya çalışıyorum şimdi mesela emaile göre arama yapıp kullanıcı bana dönüyor ama snapshot üzerinden kullanıcının bilgilerine ulaşamıyorum mesela diyelim kullanıcının idsi 5 şöyle yaparsam ulaşırım
snapshot.val().5.UserName
ama işte problemde tam burda ben oraya 5 yazamam her kullanıcının farklı id'si var nolur yardım et 4 saat oldu hala çözüm bulamadım :(

Comment: o kullanıcının id si `snapshot.key` , Bu işine yaramalı. Yaramazsa daha açık yazarsan yardımcı olmaya çalışacağım.

Comment: abi snapshot.key koydum ama sadece Users yazıyor

Comment: users tablom var hemen altında idler var her id'nin altındada o idye ait bilgiler var bilgiler sabit hepsinde aynı

Comment: zaten bana snapshot id ile birlikte dondugu icin  snapshot.key diyince artik id'ninde ustu geliyor

Comment: Yukardaki json data nı users dan itibaren update edebilirmisin ?

Comment: jsonu degistirdim bide firebase uzerinde structuterin fotografini alip koydum

Comment: Abi cozdum olayi value yerine child_added diyince direk idnin altindaki veriyi verdi dedigin gibi key getirince de idyi alabildim cok tesekkur ederim :)

Comment: işte burada sorun yok. `snapshot.key` sana `OrnekUserId` i verir. Vermesi lazım. (resmi göremiyorum, hata mesajı veriyor) ama sonuç değişmez. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot